# Node js extract data from a nested function

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am trying to process signup data for a uni project . I am using basic koa modules and I am not allowed to use express, ideally I want to get the data inside the variable `post`. I want to process the data for example to see if the password has less than 5 characters , if so i would like that the program would not redirect the user to different address but if no errors occur i would like the program to redirect to `regOk.html`, I tried many other ways like initializing the variable outside of `ctx.req.on` but none were successful . Can anyone help me ?

```
export async function postregister(ctx) {
  let bodyString = "";
  ctx.req.on("data", (chunk) => {
    bodyString += chunk;
  });
  //let collectData = new Array();
  ctx.req.on("end", () => {
    var post = querystring.parse(bodyString);
    var email = post["email"];
    var password = post["password"];
    var passbestätigen = post["passwort bestä"];
    var vorname = post["vorname"];
    var nachname = post["nachname"];
    var adresse = post["adresse"];
    var stadt = post["stadt"];
    var telefonnummer = post["telefonnummer"];
    var geburtsdatum = post["geburtsdatum"];
    var regData = model.add(ctx.db, post);
    regData.then(() => console.log("singup successful"))
    
  });

  await ctx.render("regOk.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with koa, but I believe your issue is related to the order in which your code is executed.

The event in charge of parsing the data received in the body of the request ends after the synchronic execution of your postregister method, so you never get to see the value of post in the order you'd expect.

One possible solution to go around this issue would be wrapping the parsing of data in a promise, waiting for that promise to complete, and executing then and catch functions once the processing is done.

```js
export async function postregister(ctx) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
      let bodyString = "";
      ctx.req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        bodyString += chunk;
      });
      ctx.req.on("end", async () => {
        resolve(querystring.parse(bodyString));
      });
    })
    .then(async (post) => {
      await model.add(ctx.db, post)
        .then(async () => {
          console.log("singup successful");
          await ctx.render('regOk.html');
        });
    })
    .catch(async (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      await ctx.render('error.html');
    });
}
```

This way, you handle body parsing inside the Promise, and after that completed you get the result of `querystring.parse(bodyString)` as a variable named `post` in your then handler.

Comment: I tired your Method and it worked for me,your effort is greatly appreciated